# Why doesn't using python's logical operator or in the form of "x == 5 or 4" throw an error?

Tags: python

I wonder why this code will give a result of 3 for count.

```
s = 'awb'
count = 0
for i in range (0, len(s)):
    if s[i] == 'a' or 'b':
        count += 1

print ("number of a and b: ", count)
```

I understand that in order to count the number of a and b, the if statement should look like:

```
if s[i] == 'a' or s[i] == 'b':
```

However, I am just curious why the if statement in my original code will result in all the characters in the string being counted?

Comment: Strings are truthy if they have 1 or more characters. Your statement evaluates to `(s[I] == 'a') or ('b')`, which is `(s[I] == 'a') or (True)`, which is `True`.

Comment: `if 'b':` is a valid statement (equal to `True`). The elements of `or` can be switched around without changing their meaning (unless they have a side effect of course!) so you can also say `if 'b' or s[i] == 'a':`, which demonstrates the problem more clearly.

Comment: BTW, instead of `if s[i] == 'a' or s[i] == 'b'` (and possibly adding more and more equality checks to the chain), you could do `if s[i] in ('a', 'b')`

Comment: And instead of `for i in range (0, len(s)):
    if s[i] in ('a', 'b'):`, you could just write `for c in s:
    if c in 'ab':`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
if s[i] == 'a' or 'b'
```

says if the current index of the string s == 'a' execute the code below this line. The second condition is `True` ('b' always evaluates to `True` in the context of truthiness in python). The second condition in the statement will make this if statement `True`. Therefore, count will always be incremented for each iteration the loop. Within the context of boolean evaluation a literal always evaluates to `True`. Consider the snippet below:

```
not not 'b'
```

If you execute this line of code by itself you'll see that the expression evaulates to `True`. 'b' was "casted" into a boolean value (`True` or `False`). This implicitly happens behind the scenes within the if statement in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for it to through an error. Writting `x == 5 or 4` would be evaluated as `(x == 5) or 4` So the left hand of the or will be true when x is 5 but the right hand will always be true since truthyness will say any int thats not 0 is True. Now you may think well whats the point but there are valid use cases.

lets imagine we have a game that always gives a prize on the first go regardless if you were right or not then for each turn after that you only win if your correct.

```py
prize_gauranteed = True
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == 5 or prize_gauranteed:
        print("You win a prize")
        prize_gauranteed = False
    else:
        print("No prize this time")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Guess: 10
You win a prize
Guess: 10
No prize this time
Guess: 4
No prize this time
Guess: 5
You win a prize
```